HTML5 Video is darker when there is an element on top with backdrop-filter:blue is enabled (chrome only)
I have a fullscreen HTML5 video which is covered with a UI bar. This UI bar has a frosty glass effect. I'm using backdrop-filter: blur for this. Works fine. But the video that is underneath is slightly darker when this effect is enabled.
Example: https://codepen.io/duetdigital/pen/zYQZBpm
HTML
<video class="" muted>
  <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/zg3zp70ts6e1t4a/business-scene.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div>
  <a href="#" id="button">toggle opacity of backdrop-filter:blur(15px) block</a>
</div>

(S)CSS
video {
  width:100vw;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top:200px;
  right:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

#button {
  color: #fff; 
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  padding:20px;
  display:block;
  &.hide {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

Same thing happens here: https://www.wysemeter.com
Is there a solution?
It only happens in Chrome for now. In Safari it works properly. With images it works fine, also with a background-color. It also doesn't matter if you use webm or mp4.
